# последнее число

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно в строчке извлечь последнее число
Например, идет строчка 10 213 1 3992, нужно извлечь 3992,т.е последнее число

Comment: Регулярные выражения - обязательное условие? И на каком(их) ЯП Вы готовы принять ответы?

Comment: Желательно через регулярные выражения. Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Код:***

```py
import re


string = '10 213 1 3992'

print(re.split(r' ', string)[-1])      # 3992
print(re.findall(r'\d+', string)[-1])  # 3992
print(string.split()[-1])              # 3992
```

Answer (score 1):

Через регулярки так:

```py
import re
res = re.search(r'\d+$','10 213 1 3992')
print(res.group(0)) # 3992
```

Answer (score -1):

*Java:*

```java
string = '10 213 1 3992'
String []strings = string.split(" ");
System.out.println(strings[strings.length-1]);
```